# net::ERR_FAILED zone-evergreen.js:2952

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

Using Angular 7 as front-end and Nodejs as back-end.

I deployed a web site at Amazon-web-service using IIS and when I doing API requests to the server everything works just fine.

But when a client from China is trying to use the same website and send the same API he gets a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is presented on the requested resource`

other then that error, he receives another error: `POST http:...   net::ERR_FAILED zone-evergreen.js:2952`

what is the `zone-evergreen.js` and how does it affects the cors policy?

**P.S.**

when the client browsing his mobile smartphone the API is successfully sent. the problem is happening on his computer device.

**here is the server code (node.js):**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');


app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
})
```

**here is the client sending the API request (Angular 7):**

```
public saveData(data: any): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
    };

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + this.apiName, JSON.stringify(data), httpOptions);
}
```

**the error:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are running on a CORS policy error.
In order to make this work you should enable CORS through your API and redeploy it.

im not really sure how to fix it in your Case , im just mentioning what you can research so you might fix it for yourself.

Heads up!.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your browser doesn't trust the server.so please check the error in console and there will be a link right to it. you can click on it and it will redirect to a prompt. Form there click on `advanced` then click `proceed to site.`

If you're facing a CORS error, it's because your server is accessed from  a non whitelisted place. you can simply use `CORS unblock` extension which will be available in chrome store to unblock this